# Make a loop to find the distance between stations in R

Tags: r, loops, debugging

I have made this code to find the distance between stations but in the output, there is only one value. Can you find the error?

```
df <- data.frame(
  station = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20),
  temperature = rnorm(80),
  latitude = c(40.7128, 34.0522, 41.8781, 39.9526),
  longitude = c(-74.0060, -118.2437, -87.6298, -75.1652)
)
stations <- unique(df$station)

my_points <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(df$station)), ncol = length(unique(df$station)))

# Loop through each station combination
for (i in 1:length(stations)) {
  for (j in 1:length(stations)) {
    # Get temperatures for the two stations
    lat1 <- df$latitude[df$station == stations[i]]
    lon1 <- df$longitude[df$station == stations[i]]
    lat2 <- df$latitude[df$station == stations[j]]
    lon2 <- df$longitude[df$station == stations[j]]
    my_points[i, j] <- as.vector(dist(matrix(c(lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2),
                                             nrow = 2)))  
    
  }
}

distance_df <- as.data.frame(my_points)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues here:

- Your input data frame might not look the way you expect it to - the latitude and longitude columns are recycled so you have multiple different coordinates for the same station. Try adding `rep()` in the lat and long columns as well as `station`.
- In your code `lat1 <- df$latitude[df$station == stations[i]]` returns a vector, because there are multiple matches. I think you're expecting a single value. Use only the first matching element (since they are now all the same elements in the vector after adding `rep()` as above):

```r
df <- data.frame(
  station = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20),
  temperature = rnorm(80),
  latitude = rep(c(40.7128, 34.0522, 41.8781, 39.9526), each = 20),
  longitude = rep(c(-74.0060, -118.2437, -87.6298, -75.1652), each = 20)
)
stations <- unique(df$station)

my_points <- matrix(NA, nrow = length(unique(df$station)), ncol = length(unique(df$station)))

# Loop through each station combination
for (i in 1:length(stations)) {
  for (j in 1:length(stations)) {
    # Get temperatures for the two stations
    lat1 <- df$latitude[df$station == stations[i]][1]
    lon1 <- df$longitude[df$station == stations[i]][1]
    lat2 <- df$latitude[df$station == stations[j]][1]
    lon2 <- df$longitude[df$station == stations[j]][1]
    my_points[i, j] <- as.vector(dist(matrix(c(lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2),
                                             nrow = 2)))  
    
  }
}

distance_df <- as.data.frame(my_points)
```

This gives:

```r
         V1       V2       V3        V4
1  0.000000 44.73631 13.67355  1.386235
2 44.736313  0.00000 31.59835 43.480707
3 13.673546 31.59835  0.00000 12.612446
4  1.386235 43.48071 12.61245  0.000000
```

A slightly better way of finding unique stations:

```r
unique(df[, c("station", "latitude", "longitude")])
```

You can then loop over those instead:

```r
# Loop through each station combination
for (i in 1:length(stations)) {
  for (j in 1:length(stations)) {
    # Get temperatures for the two stations
    lat1 <- unique_df$latitude[unique_df$station == stations[i]]
    lon1 <- unique_df$longitude[unique_df$station == stations[i]]
    lat2 <- unique_df$latitude[unique_df$station == stations[j]]
    lon2 <- unique_df$longitude[unique_df$station == stations[j]]
    my_points[i, j] <- as.vector(dist(matrix(c(lon1,lon2,lat1,lat2),
                                             nrow = 2)))  
    
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There’s no need for a loop — just subset to unique station latitudes and longitudes, and use `dist()` on that:

```r
# assuming each station has a unique location
stations <- unique(df[c("latitude", "longitude")])
rownames(stations) <- unique(df$station)

dist(stations) |> 
  as.matrix() |> 
  as.data.frame()
```

```
          A        B        C         D
A  0.000000 44.73631 13.67355  1.386235
B 44.736313  0.00000 31.59835 43.480707
C 13.673546 31.59835  0.00000 12.612446
D  1.386235 43.48071 12.61245  0.000000
```

*Example data:*

```r
df <- data.frame(
  station = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 20),
  temperature = rnorm(80),
  latitude = rep(c(40.7128, 34.0522, 41.8781, 39.9526), each = 20),
  longitude = rep(c(-74.0060, -118.2437, -87.6298, -75.1652), each = 20)
)
```